# How can I fix this Discord SOCKS5 HTTP Proxy Error

Tags: linux, discord

**Summarize the problem:**
My problem is with Discord on Linux while attempting to run off a HTTP proxy on port 1080.

**Describe what you’ve tried:**
Everything under the sun. The closest I've come to being able to get this to successfully work is making it past Discord update.
One Answer said to try this:
npm config set strict-ssl=false

This did not work.

When appropriate, show some code:

```
$ nohup ssh -D1080 proxy_server &
$ http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 /usr/share/discord/Discord --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

**Could anybody help me with this? I'm following this guide:**
https://gist.github.com/mzpqnxow/ca4b4ae0accf2d3b275537332ccbe86e

**Here's the error I'm getting:**

```
Starting app.  
Starting updater.  
[Modules] Modules initializing  
[Modules] Distribution: remote  
[Modules] Host updates: enabled  
[Modules] Module updates: enabled  
[Modules] Module install path: /home/siren/.config/discord/0.0.13/modules  
[Modules] Module installed file path: /home/siren/.config/discord/0.0.13/modules/installed.json  
[Modules] Module download path: /home/siren/.config/discord/0.0.13/modules/pending  
[Modules] No updates to install  
[Modules] Checking for host updates.  
Error downloading with electron net: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
Falling back to node net library..  
[Updates] Error fetching https://discord.com/api/updates/stable?platform=linux&version=0.0.13: self signed certificate in certificate chain  
[Modules] Host update failed: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain  
[Modules] Checking for host updates.  
Error downloading with electron net: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT  
Falling back to node net library..    
[Updates] Error fetching https://discord.com/api/updates/stable?platform=linux&version=0.0.13: self signed certificate in certificate chain  
[Modules] Host update failed: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain  
[Modules] Checking for host updates.  
Error downloading with electron net: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT  
Falling back to node net library..
```